# Which query is optimized when I get monthly data with respect to sale.purchase_date using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a same result when I execute both queries from different functions. I just wanted to know which query is optimized or logically correct (see query 1 and 2 below).

I get monthly data with respect to `sale.purchase_date`

Query 1

```
SELECT sales.purchase_date FROM `sales` 
WHERE sales.purchase_date LIKE  '2012-06-%';
```

Query 2

```
SELECT sales.purchase_date FROM `sales` 
WHERE MONTH(sales.purchase_date) = '6' AND YEAR(sales.purchase_date) = '2012';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those require you to do a table scan because you need to examine the `purchase_date` to see if the row will be in and can't use an index. I suggest you use a `BETWEEN` query so you can make use of any index on `purchase_date`:

```
WHERE sales.purchase_date BETWEEN '2012-06-01' AND '2012-06-30'
```